# Why does assiging var node= this.obj inside a protoype not this.obj when node changes?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm implementing a simple linked list in javascript using prototypes. I came across something I don't quite understand -

```
var Node = function( value ) {
  this.value = value;
  this.next = null;
};

var List = function( head ) {
  this.head = null;  
};

List.prototype.insert = function( value ) {
   if ( this.head === null ) {
       this.head = new Node( value ); 
   } else {
     var aNode = this.head;
     console.log( 'same: ' + (aNode === this.head)); // prints true
     while ( aNode.next !== null ) {
       aNode = aNode.next;
     }
     var node = new Node( value );
     aNode.next = node;
     console.log( 'Head: ' + this.head.value );  //prints 1
     console.log( 'Node: ' + aNode.value );  //prints 2,3,4
   }
};

var aList = new List();
aList.insert( 1 );
aList.insert( 2 );
aList.insert( 3 );
aList.insert( 4 );
```

If this.head and aNode share a reference, changing aNode to aNode.next doesnt change this.head. Can someone explain why? I'm new to prototypes.

Comment: @neuDev33 - In other words, don't edit your question in a way that changes the original meaning of the question.  Instead, [create a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Thanks T.J.Crowder and @gilly3, will change this question back to the original.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the order of operations. You want parentheses on that:

```
console.log( 'same: ' + (aNode === this.head))
// ---------------------^-------------------^
```

Without them, it's effectively

```
console.log( ('same: ' + aNode) === this.head)
```

...(which is, of course, false) because `+` has a [higher precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) than `===`. It's the same reason that `if (a + 5 === 6)` is true when `a` is `1`.

Comment: @neuDevs33 TJ's answer should fix your problem. Show how your calling it and an example value, I can make your logic way more efficient and simplified for you.

Comment: @JordanDavis: done, and I have another doubt, thanks!

Comment: @neuDev33 Okay got it yea give me a sec I'll post the code. In the meantime if you want to learn more about prototyping a really good guide is here ---> http://tobyho.com/2010/11/22/javascript-constructors-and/

Answer (score 0):

In your `console.log` it is first evaluating the concatenation of `same` string and `aNode` and then comparing to `this.head`:

Change it to:

```
console.log( 'same:' + (aNode === this.head))
```

or:

```
console.log( 'same:', aNode === this.head)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick... let me know.

1. Declare a new list, example --- `var chores = new List("chores");`
2. Declare a new list item, example --- `chores.add("Mow lawns.");`

//CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
//LIST (OBJECT CONSTRUCTOR)
var List = function(title){
    this.title = title;
    this.datetime = new Date(); 
    this.items = []; 
};

//LIST (OBJECT METHOD - ADD)
//ALL OBJECTS CREATED FROM THE LIST OBJECT CONSTRUCTOR ABOVE INHERIT THIS METHOD
List.prototype.add = function(val){
    this.items.push(val);
};

//CREATE NEW LIST OBJECT CALLED (CHORES)
var chores = new List("chores");

//INPUT DATA USING LIST METHOD ADD, WHICH OBJECT CHORES INHERITED WHEN IT WAS INSTANTIATED (CREATED)
chores.add("Mow lawns.");
chores.add("Make dinner.");
chores.add("Drive to the store.");

//VIEW OUTPUT
console.log(chores);
console.log(chores.items);
console.log(chores.items[0]);
console.log(chores.items[1]);
console.log(chores.items[2]);
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: while this works, im trying to emulate linked list operations in javascript by creating a linked list class, I dont think the above code achieves that since we end up using an array itself to push things into.

Comment: @neuDev33 I'm not sure I understand what you mean by linked list operation? You can access any item in the list by calling (chores.items[0]) or whichever one you want... you could do via json where you can call (chores.items.0), but at the end of the day whatever you specify it has to be a unique property so that it's not overriding the others, so it only makes since to use an incremental approach (0,1,2,3,etc)

Comment: To clarify - im trying to implement a linked list internally in javascript as opposed to using any existing data types like Arrays. If you look at my implementation, it would look similar to any linked list implementation in other languages. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @neuDev33 it doesn't, from my understanding you want the user to be able to create a list and list items per that list. Using a object property thats an array vs. a nested json object really doesn't matter, either the Array index has to be incremented or an array of nested json objects with unique property names (ie. incremented). The only difference would be in calling (chores.items[0]) with brackets vs. the json dot syntax (chores.items.0) either way if you need to use a unique identifier for the value.

Comment: I agree with you. If someone were to use this code, it would probably be better to use the array implementation vs my object implementation(both achieve the end result of pushing items in a list). But I've written this code to understand prototypes better, so im not really worried that this is not the best implementation. I probably should have made that clear before.

Comment: Btw, if you have an answer to this question - "If this.head and aNode share a reference, changing aNode to aNode.next doesnt change this.head. Can someone explain why? I'm new to prototypes.", I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: @neuDev33 I'll walk you through it... In your else statement you set (aNode = this.head).... then you run while loop (aNode.next !== null) your problem is that (aNode) doesn't have a property (next) so it will always fail, (aList) however does have a (next) property... then you create (node) which will inherit properties (value,next)... then you set (aNode) which still doesn't have the property (next) so it will always fail, equal to node which has the properties (value:value,next:null).

Comment: @neuDev33 prototyping is like assigning a object a property with a value thats a function but when nested it's technically called a (method), so when I declare List.prototype.add whats going on is I'm declaring a (add) method to the List object so that every object created from the List (constructor) will inherit this add method which then enables me to call chores.add() because chores was constructed from the List function (constructor) and therefore inherits this add method.